# I sent ETH to my old wallet but I cant retrieve it anymore

Tags: metamask, etherscan

Hello hope you all safe and sound!

Transaction Hash: 0x1ea0295cd02df138b009e8197d9137981eb28c100befe154db61498124f34191

I am begging for help. I accidentally sent my ETH to the wrong address "0xfD3a8D90467fb869Ff49DCfD32Df8C1E9774B78a" just last night. I try to recover it using my metamask if that wallet exist on my MM but unfortunately i was unable to recover that wallet. My correct wallet should be "0xf9A9d3025ab51C35209E8f848E7178395f1EcD9a" Please help me its a lot of money for me and its for my school. Is there anyway I can get it back and transfer to my wallet? I already contacted the support for this.

Comment: if this is some exchange contract, only they would know if the funds are recoverable. but as a general rule, without owning private key you cant recover it so sending to wrong address means - lost funds

Comment: Oh no. Please help me. The fund is stuck at the wallet address :( maybe I can still at least rectify this since the transaction is there.

Comment: Where did you get the address? One possibility is to try contacting the address owner to help.

Comment: You can only contact the owner of the address and try to get it to give you your money back. Good luck.

Comment: But there's no owner on that account. Which is mine.